# Mockear llamada a servicio web externo con Mockito en Java

Tags: java, mockito

Teniendo este código:

```
private ConsultaCiudadanoStub clienteConsultaCiudadanoWS;

clienteGestionColectivosWS = new GestionColectivosWsStub();

clienteGestionColectivosWS._getServiceClient().getOptions().setTo(new org.apache.axis2.addressing.EndpointReference(Inicializacion.getUrlWsGestionColectivos()));
```

¿Cómo puedo mockear una llamada a clienteGestionColectivosWS, siendo este un servicio web externo, con Mockito en un test con Java?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor mira en la ayuda [ask] , [qué puedo preguntar](/help/on-topic) y [qué no](/help/dont-ask). La pregunta tal cual la tienes ahora es muy amplia y es probable que sea cerrada. Te sugiero que la borres y cuando tengas una pregunta clara lo hagas con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hola David, como dice @Awes0meM4n deberias hacer una pregunta mas clara y concreta, con el codigo de **lo que has intentado** y qué fallos o complicaciones te da. Un saludo

Comment: Te recomiendo de agregar un test que quieres implementar con código, para que puedes recibir una respuesta concreta como usar Mockito en to caso de uso.

Answer (score 1):

la manera de usar `Mockito` es bastante fácil. Solo tienes que crear un mock de la clase que quieras:

```
clienteGestionColectivosWS = Mockito.mock(GestionColectivosWsStub.class);
```

Si quisieses que te tuviese un comportamiento determinado, por ejemplo, que te devuelva un objeto concreto cuando haces una llamada, tendrías que usar `when`y hacer algo parecido a esto: `when(clienteGestionColectivosWS.METODO(PARAMETROS)).thenReturn(OBJETO_DE_VUELTA);`

Espero que con esto te sirva para empezar. Si no, siempre puedes tirar de la documentación (http://site.mockito.org/).